# Aren't professionals from different countries the same?

Tags: undergraduate, international

I am a college senior in America. I was born in a very poor country, not in North America nor in Europe. I recently visited my home country and encountered a teacher from an elite high school. He told me that teachers from top high schools often have access to high school-leaving national exam papers ahead of the exams.

I also remember that when I was in high school(in my native country) a lab tech told a group of us, that students from even poorer schools in the countryside, who only saw equipped labs on the day of the national exams, often had their grades "boosted".

The high school teacher I met also told me that in addition to pure merit in national exams, exam graders also considered quotas when assigning grades ie how many slots do they need in med/engineering schools.

Are there any resources you would recommend that document and explain the motivations behind such practices? Of course, if I go to admissions officers of colleges in my country, they would tell me that all admissions and grading is based on pure merit only.

Where can I get the "real skinny" about such things?

Leaders in developing countries often travel abroad for medical treatment. Privacy considerations aside, isn't a physician/engineer from (insert your favorite third-world country here) just a good as his equivalent in Germany?

**CLARIFICATION**
I apologise if my question has confused you. There's a book called "Comrade Einstein". It describes systematic discrimination against Jews in Russian math departments. Link is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/981256358X). Other similar books have been written, but I don't have them nearby. If I was a Jewish parent living in Russia, a book such as the above would make me want to send my children elsewhere. And, if anyone asked I would at least have some documentation, that would make a plausible defense of my belief and not make me look paranoid.

Are there any similar books, reports etc that deal with "3rd-world" countries?

Comment: I do not see how the first part of the post is connected to the last. Can you clarify? Also off-topic from my perspective.

Comment: Political leaders and my native countrymen with means often look down on our professionals. Usually for the reasons stated above. That's where the first part of my question comes in.

Comment: @Snijderfrey: If you feel that this topic can't be discussed here, please recommend an alternative forum.

Comment: No one has to recommend a different platform, we can, however, point out that it is off-toipic here. You should read the FAQ's before posting.

Comment: @SolarMike: I appreciate that. I am not demanding anything, if you feel that it's off-topic, fine.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to know what illegeal, unwritten rules exist in your country?

Comment: @user111388: Not my country per se. But, do such things really happen anywhere or is it just one of those strange things people talk about eg "Little Green Men", that have little basis in reality?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me what you’re asking, but I think you’ve answered your own question. If you needed medical treatment and could afford to go anywhere for it, would you prefer getting it in a country where “teachers from top ... schools often have access to ... exam papers ahead of the exams” and where many other similar corrupt practices exist, or in a less corrupt place where someone’s MD certificate actually means what it claims to mean?  And as for your last question, how do you determine what is “equivalent” in a place where, due to such problems, formal credentials mean little?

Comment: @user1801060: Of course, no place is 100percent perfect. But in poorer places, there tends to be more corruption. In some countries, you get your grades for a bribe. Of course, this cannot be a quality education then. In richer countries, there is less corruption.

Comment: @DanRomik: Despite being distrusted by politicians and rich people, doctors do fairly well in poor countries. A 3rd-world MD would consider himself just as good as any German MD. He would dismiss the incidents I've reported as one-off mishaps. Here's what I'd like to know: would you send your child to a 3rd world country to study medicine? Apart from concerns about him being kidnapped etc, is there any study/report that would make you doubt the quality of education in such places? Sure their politicians are corrupt, but that wouldn't necessarily mean their academic institutions also are.

Comment: @user1801060 I haven’t studied the issue of the education of doctors in particular. And I also think the label “third world” is outdated and misleading. But to give a sort of answer to your question, I would not recommend to my child to pursue his/her education (in medicine or any other subject) in a country that ranked poorly for corruption, for example according to [this corruption index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_Perceptions_Index).

Comment: @DanRomik: Please see the clarification I've added to my question.

Comment: The medical example might not be such a good one. The key to good medical treatment is routine. A German physician is used to the diseases resulting from a western lifestyle (little physical exercise, lots of meat, drinking, smoking etc.) which a leader might have, because the German treats such patients every day. A doctor in a low income country simply is not, his leader might be the first such patient he sees in his life. This doesn't say anything about the quality of the doctor though, as in the same way a general German physician will have no experience in treating malaria for example.

Comment: @user111388: Please see the clarification I've added to my question.

Comment: @Snijderfrey: Please see the clarification I've added to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the treatment of professionals of all kinds is highly variable by country and partly determined by long lived cultural factors, there is no place to get a definitive answer unless someone has done some research on it.

In some cultures, parts of India come to mind, professors are very highly regarded as they can provide a boos upwards in a stratified country. I've had students literally kneeling at my feet (just for lack of chairs) in my office. When I expressed discomfort at that, some students from India said that, no, it feel perfectly natural to be kneeling at the feet of their guru.

In some other places, professors get spat upon.

However, to say things are equal is a mistake. Often a good education depends on an institution having a lot of money for, say, laboratories, as you note. It is harder to get qualified to a certain standard in poorer places than in richer ones, just because of available resources. I suspect there is a positive correlation between the quality of education in a country and the economic well being there. It isn't perfect, of course. Even in the US, the quality of pre-college education is suffering from want of resources in spite of the US being a fairly rich country.

But cultural differences can also lead to bad effects such as discrimination. Some well qualified medical doctors, moving to the US, find that they aren't allowed to practice medicine and the path to a license is very arduous.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In places where there are disadvantages, are there other criteria apart from grades? You are a lecturer and in many poor countries you have an almost "life or death" say in a student's financial future. If I come from a notoriously corrupt, tribalistic country, has anyone written anything about how high-schoolers and undergrads are graded?

Comment: It is possible it is explored in local press and in articles by local or regional publications. But in corrupt societies it can be dangerous to discuss things publicly. In the US we can complain pretty openly, even if we get push back.